# Schema Registry Incompatible

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

How to check previous schemas registered in Registry?

I'm trying to register but I am getting "Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject" exception

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility checks will only operate against the latest stored subject version

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#sr-api-compatibility

You'd check the schemas using the subject and version number(s)

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#get--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions-(versionId-%20version)-schema

---

Neither will tell you "why" it is incompatible, but Avro has clear documentation on that, for example

Comment: Is there a way to find out why the schema fails compatibility check when I receive `"is_compatible": "false"` when calling `/compatibility/subjects/{schema_name}/versions/{last_version}` ?

Comment: As answered, the API doesn't return this information. You will need to read the relevant documentation for the serialization format you are using. Or you can create a new question here and upload both of your schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

- Command to get all versions of the previously registered schemas

> SchemaRegistryURL/subjects/topicname-value/versions

- Command to get a specific version of all previously registered Schemas

> SchemaRegistryURL/subjects/topicname-value/versions/version

Schema Compatibility option might not set it correctly, in which case you can reset the Compatibility using the following command and try re-registering your schema.

curl -k -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"compatibility": "NONE"}' SchemaRegistryURL/config/topic-value

From https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#summary

> ### Compatibility
>
> **Transitive** compatibility checking is important once you have more than two versions of a schema for a given subject. If compatibility is
> configured as transitive, then it checks compatibility of a new schema
> against all previously registered schemas; otherwise, it checks
> compatibility of a new schema only against the latest schema.
>
> For example, if there are three schemas for a subject that change in
> order X-2, X-1, and X then:
>
> **transitive**: ensures compatibility between X-2 <==> X-1 and X-1 <==> X and X-2 <==> X
>
> **non-transitive**: ensures compatibility between X-2 <==> X-1 and X-1 <==> X, but not necessarily X-2 <==> X
>
> The Confluent Schema Registry default compatibility type BACKWARD is
> non-transitive, which means that it’s not BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE. As a
> result, new schemas are checked for compatibility only against the
> latest schema.
>
> **BACKWARD**: (default) consumers using X-2 can read data written by producers X-1
>
> **BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE**: consumers using X-2 can read data written by producers using X-1, and X
>
> **FORWARD**: consumers using X-1 can read data written by producers using X-2
>
> **FORWARD_TRANSITIVE**: consumers using X-1 or X can read data written by producers using X-2
>
> **FULL**: the new schema is forward and backward compatible with the latest registered schema
>
> **FULL_TRANSITIVE**: the new schema is forward and backward compatible with all previously registered schemas
>
> **NONE**: schema compatibility checks are disabled

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in [Schema Evolution](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#schema-evolution-and-compatibility).

The Confluent Schema Registry default compatibility type is BACKWARD so you cannot add more fields or change datatype.

You need to change the compatibility.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#schema-evolution-and-compatibility